# Distortions when fading out mp3 files on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio

I have an mp3 file that is almost sine-wave like, due to which whenever i fade it out, there are distortions. I need fadeouts over really short periods of time (0.05 seconds). The timer resolution is not enough to cover this. As a result i need to read out the samples, adjust their gain, and play them back. I did this in the original flash/AS3 version of the app but can someone tell me how to do this via core-audio on ios ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone wanted something similar, i managed to do this. Basically, i used AudioQueues and Extended Audio File Services.

I read in the mp3 files using ExtAudioFileServices while specifying a 32 bit PCM format. I then start an AudioQueue and in the call back i read in from the buffers corresponding to files, adjust their gain, and copy them to the queue buffer. Voila :D